# How do I get CMake Tools to compile programs in Visual Studio Code with C++11 (or higher) features?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-code, cmake, c++17

I'm new to CMake in general so hopefully there is something simple I'm doing wrong but I'm pulling my hair out trying to find the solution. I can't get CMake tools to compile even a trivial program with c++11 (or higher features). Ideally I'd like to enable c++17.

For example, if my entire main() function is

```
int main(int, char**) 
{
    auto number{9};

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following 2 errors and 1 warning when attempting a build:

```
error: declaration of variable 'number' with deduced type 'auto' requires an initializer

error: expected ';' at end of declaration

warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
```

My VSCode C++ settings are set to the C++17 standard, and I don't get any Intellisense errors or warnings when **writing** the code, just when I try to **build** using the CMake Tools extension.

I've also tried adding the following to my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
```

What am I missing? Thanks very much!

**Platform and Versions**

Operating System: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

CMake Version: 3.16.2

VSCode Version: 1.41.1

CMake Tools Extension Version: 1.2.3

Compiler/Toolchain: Clang 10.0.0

Comment: Please show the contents of your `CMakeLists.txt` file

Comment: Try `target_compile_features(your_project PUBLIC cxx_std_17)`.

Comment: Try building with high verbosity so you can see which compiler flags are actually used.

Comment: Have you tried `set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS ON)`? The error message does say it's an extension...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, and as I suspected it turned out to be a simple mistake and fix.

Originally, my CMakeLists.txt file looked like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(JRPG VERSION 0.1.0)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

add_executable(JRPG main.cpp)

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
```

When I moved those bottom three lines up **directly underneath the project name and version line (see below)**, the build worked as expected. I don't yet know exactly why that worked but I'm sure I'll figure it out soon enough as I dive deeper into the documentation. Thanks!

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(JRPG VERSION 0.1.0)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

add_executable(JRPG main.cpp)

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```